# Is there an int128?

Tags: delphi

I need an int128 (and/or int256).

Is there a library or way in which I can use that in Delphi?

Note that I do not want to muck around with strings and such, support as close as possible to int64 would be ideal.

There's [BigInteger](http://sergworks.wordpress.com/tag/biginteger/), but this calls a dll to do its work, which is not acceptable.

I remember there being another library for big numbers, but I cannot remember the name...

Comment: There used to be a library called Huge Integer Tools, but I don't know if it is still supported or even around anymore...

Comment: You'd be better off writing your own dedicated record to do this. Well, that is if you want performance. A generic bigint class would be over the top. A record with two Int64 fields and some operators would do the job nicely.

Comment: Maybe this [BigNum](http://webtweakers.com/swag/MATH/0113.PAS.html) unit?

Comment: Yes and some MMX etc assembly, I know, for now I just need to get stuff working, will muck around with the optimizations later.

Comment: @NGLN, lol that's 16bit assembly; been a long time since I messed around with that.

Answer (score 1):

OK, found it at: http://sourceforge.net/projects/bigint-dl/

**BigInt** is the Delphi library providing operations with extremely large integer numbers, known as multi-precision arithmetics. Our primary goal is to achieve maximum performance of calculations.

The sourcecode is nicely documented <kbd>in Chinese :-(</kbd>

It uses mostly x86 32bit assembly (no MMX etc, which is a pity).

Comment: I'm pretty sure Ian Hickson would not approve of that use of `kbd` :) It's a semantic nightmare!

Comment: Everyone knows Ian Hickson is tripping on acid.

Answer (score 0):

This is an open source unit that I have used in the past for math with 'unlimited' sized integers: 
http://www.bvbcode.com/code/b1uxniwl-1626766
Would that be what you were looking for?

Ps
I am on my phone now. If this is helpful I will improve the formatting later.

Comment: Yikes, that uses strings to store numbers in, 1 byte per digit. (2 bytes with the new strings). That's going to be slow.

Comment: @johan, excuse me? Does that link work different for you? It uses a record with an array of int64's? I'd say that is quite similar to the record with the intended array of cardinals you asked about yesterday. There are functions which convert the arbitrary big integer to string with a optional radix but that is merely to make the number readable for humans. If you want to reinvent the wheel that is fine but I would appreciate it if you showed a little less dedain for people trying to help you.